# Python - cannot import slycot module in spyder (RuntimeError & ImportError)

Tags: python, importerror, spyder

When I try to import the slycot module in spyder (version 2.2), I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 7 but this version of numpy is 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/slycot/__init__.py",  
line 4, in <module>
    from slycot.analysis import ab01nd,ab05md,ab05nd,ab07nd,ab08nd, ab09ad
  File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/slycot/analysis.py",
line 21, in <module>
    from slycot import _wrapper
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Now, when I import slycot in the python shell through my terminal, there are no problems at all. I think the reason why there are no problems through the terminal, is that I recently installed numpy 1.7.1. Spyder on the other hand still uses numpy 1.6.2.,hence the error.

I tried to change the numpy version in spyder, but so far that didn't work. 
When I change the numpy(6) folder in my spyder lib with the recently installed numpy(7), I get the following error (in spyder):

```
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
    its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
    your python intepreter from there.
```

What is the best way to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(Spyder dev here) At the moment it's not possible for the user to install anything inside the app. I guess you moved your slycot module from another interpreter to our App (because of the `numpy` error you mention).

The right way to use different modules not present in the app, is to change the path of your interpreter in:

Tools > Preferences > Console > Advanced settings > Python executable

If you installed slycot using your system Python, you have to select

`/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I used different modules such as sympy, Tkinker etc. in Spyder through copying the module folder in the Spyder lib after installation. This worked fine so far. When I change the path of my interpreter I get the following message:
"python: posix_spawn: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No such file or directory" 

I probably did something wrong, do I also have to change PYTHONSTARTUP?

Comment: What do you get when you run `which python` in a terminal? That's the path you need to put in _Python executable_, not the one you are selecting. Besides, the app comes with Sympy and Tkinter. The problem with slycot is that it was compiled with a different numpy version, as you correctly guessed.

Comment: I get '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python', which is already tried to put in Python executable, but then I get the error: 'ImportError: cannot import name urandom'. I tried to find a solution to solve that but so far unsuccessful..

Comment: What Spyder version are you using?

Comment: Spyder 2.2.0dev, ("Python 2.7.3, Qt 4.8.2, PyQt4 (API v2) 4.9.4 on Darwin")

Comment: That's why too old (I think from 5 months ago). Please uninstall it, and download and install our latest DMG. This one has a fix for the `ImportError: cannot import name urandom` you mentioned. I'm sorry for the inconvenience but previous versions were just for testing purposes.

Comment: Allright, so I did that, now there's a problem with the scipy module(that comes with the app):  `ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper`. (Sorry for the trouble, but I really appreciate your help)

Comment: That's the scipy version you have installed in your system Python, not the one that comes with the app (because all our libraries are inside `/Applications/Spyder.app/`). Now another couple of questions: are you running Snow Leopard? or did you installed you scipy version with universal support or only for 32 bits?

Comment: I run Lion 10.7.5, and I installed scipy from this link (the dmg file): http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.12.0/, but now I see this is for Mac OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard), however this one worked fine before?

Comment: This is probably a problem between the way our app was compiled and how scipy was built. What happens if you install the right version of scipy?

Comment: I installed the right version (the ScipySuperpack) and the error is gone, but now I have some problems with pylab: `... return interpd(dedent(func))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.x-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/matplotlib/docstring.py", line 39, in __call__
    func.__doc__ = func.__doc__ and func.__doc__ % self.params
KeyError: 'Line2D'`. I can import matplotlib without errors, but when I try importing pylab (from matplotlib import pylab) it gives the previous error. Again, the python shell through the terminal gives no errors.

Comment: This seems like a simple error (although I haven't seen it before). Are you able to generate plots despite of it?

Comment: No plots, but now I reinstalled matplotlib, through the terminal (instead of the dmg-file) and the previous error is gone, now i've got `no module named sip`. (The rest of the modules are working fine), although I installed SIP.